# jenkins manually install plugins

Tags: jenkins, plugins

My IT department has blocked internet access to all but a few sites and they don't want to keep adding new sites to the proxy.  Consequently, during the installation of Jenkins on linux, none of the plugins were added.  Is there a way to download all the plugins and install them manually?  There are too many to download and install them individually.

The best solution would be if I could re-install Jenkins without needing to connect to the internet at all.

Comment: To download all the plugins try take a look at [install-plugins.sh](https://github.com/jenkinsci/docker/blob/master/install-plugins.sh) which comes with the official Jenkins docker image. To install the plugins on a Jenkins you can just put hpi's in JENKINS_HOME and restart. A more flexible solution will be to setup a local Update Center using [Juseppe](https://github.com/yandex-qatools/juseppe/wiki/Complete-Guide-of-own-update-center-using-Juseppe). However, at least once you will need to download the binaries outside the firewallled network. Also you won't be able to get updates easily.